# Do not redirect subdomain in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I wrote this redirect rules for my primary domain:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^projetomedicina\.com\.br$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.projetomedicina\.com\.br$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site[/]?$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(lojinha_\.projetomedicina\.com\.br$ [NC]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ /portal
RedirectMatch 301 ^/site/$ http://projetomedicina.com.br/portal
```

But then I try to access one of my subdomains: http://lojinha.projetomedicina.com.br it redirects to /portal.

How can I modify my .htaccess in order to do not allow redirects from my subdomain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RedirectMatch` is directive from `mod_alias`. What you need is `RewriteRule` here:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?projetomedicina\.com\.br$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(site)?/?$ /portal [L,R=302,NC]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd like also redirect /site to /portal, but not redirect the /site subfolders. Do you know the way I could do that?

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. What I want is '/' redirect to '/portal' (that's ok), but '/site' did not redirects to '/portal'. I need this without redirect subfolders of '/site', in order for me to access some files in '/site/attachments'

Comment: This will redirect `/` and `/site` and `/site/` to `/portal`. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Yes, but I need to have access for subfolders of /site. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yes this rule won't impact `/site/attachments`. Make sure you don't have .htaccess in `/site/` and there is **no other rule**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95017/discussion-between-julio-sousa-and-anubhava).